# Why is Table Schema inference from Scala case classes not working in this official example

Tags: apache-flink

I am having trouble with Schema inference from Scala case classes during conversion from DataStreams to Tables in Flink. I've tried reproducing [the examples given in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/#examples-for-fromdatastream) but cannot get them to work. I'm wondering whether this might be a bug?

I have commented on a [somewhat related issue in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74043531/20173985). My workaround is not using case classes but defining somewhat laboriously a DataStream[Row] with return type annotations.

Still I would like to learn if it is somehow possible to get the Schema inference from case classes working.

I'm using Flink 1.15.2 with Scala 2.12.7. I'm using the java libraries but install `flink-scala` separately.

This is my implementation of Example 1 as a quick Sanity Check:

```
import org.apache.flink.runtime.testutils.MiniClusterResourceConfiguration
import org.apache.flink.test.util.MiniClusterWithClientResource
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment

import java.time.Instant

class SanitySuite extends AnyFunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {
  val flinkCluster = new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
    new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
      .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
      .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
      .build
  )

  before {
    flinkCluster.before()
  }

  after {
    flinkCluster.after()
  }

  test("Verify that table conversion works as expected") {
    val env      = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    case class User(name: String, score: java.lang.Integer, event_time: java.time.Instant)

    // create a DataStream
    val dataStream = env.fromElements(
      User("Alice", 4, Instant.ofEpochMilli(1000)),
      User("Bob", 6, Instant.ofEpochMilli(1001)),
      User("Alice", 10, Instant.ofEpochMilli(1002))
    )

    val table =
      tableEnv.fromDataStream(
        dataStream
      )
    table.printSchema()
  }
}
```

According to documentation this should result in:

```
(
 `name` STRING,
 `score` INT,
 `event_time` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9)
)
```

What I get:

```
(
  `f0` RAW('SanitySuite$User$1', '...')
)
```

If I instead modify my code in line with Example 5 - that is explicitly define a Schema that mirrors the case class, I instead get an error which very much looks like it results from the inability of extracting the case class fields:

`Unable to find a field named 'event_time' in the physical data type derived from the given type information for schema declaration. Make sure that the type information is not a generic raw type. Currently available fields are: [f0]`

Comment: were you able to get a solution ? running into the same issue

Comment: apparently the java equivalent works fine. its only scala that has an issue

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the imports, you are importing java classes and using scala classes for pojo.

Using following works:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala.StreamTableEnvironment

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
```